# How can I run a bash script automatically?

Tags: bash, kali-linux

I have a script named `run.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /root/yowsup-master/src/
./yowsup-cli --interactive no --wait --autoack --config config.example
```

This script executes another script.

I tried adding my script path in `/etc/rc.local` but it doesn’t seem to work.

I also added it to startup application in [Kali Linux](http://www.kali.org) it also doesn’t work.

I want my `run.sh` to execute automatically in the background when the computer starts.

Comment: The labels do not represent the actual contents of this question.  Even the title should talk about "a script" or "a command" instead of specifying bash.  

Why the label "python"?

Comment: @RaúlSalinas-Monteagudo Is yowsup-cli working, I mean can you send and received  messages ?

Answer (score 7):

Easy.  Use a crontab entry like this:

```
@reboot  /replace/with/the/path/to/run.sh
```

To use that on your system, the best way is to never edit `/etc/rc.local` manually, but by just running `crontab -e` to edit your crontab entries. More details [on this site](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/).